# Is there a nullability attribute similar to MemberNotNull, but ensures a member is not null just before the method is called?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have this code:

```
    private static string? _foo;

    private static void Step1()
    {
      if (_foo is null) { return; }

      Step2();
    }

    private static void Step2()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(_foo.Length); // This warns of Dereference of a possibly null reference
    }
```

What I would like to do is something like what the `MemberNotNull` attribute does, but instead of promising a member is not null after the method, it instead promises that the member is not null at the moment the method is called.

So if I could attribute my method like `[MemberNotNullBefore(nameof(_foo))] private static void Step2()` and then instead of the warning happening inside that method, if I removed the first line below it should warn me that `_foo` is possibly null next to the method call:

```
      if (_foo is null) { return; }

      Step2(); // This should warn that _foo is possibly null if the first line is removed
```

I know I could just accept `_foo` as an argument for the `Step2` method but is there a way to achieve this using nullability attributes from C# 8?

Comment: I think passing arguments is the most appropriate solution in this case unless we can find a way to follow the nullable state multiple levels deeper in order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pattern

```cs
private static string? _foo;

public static bool TryStep1([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string value)
{
    value = _foo;
    return _foo is not null;
}

private static void Step2(string foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Length); // foo is not nullable -> no warning
}
```

And then use like this:

```cs
if (TryStep1(out var foo)) {
    Step2(foo);
}
```

Note that the `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]` attribute supresses the message *"`_foo` may be null here"*.

Maybe the field `_foo` isn't required anymore, if the value can be passed from one method to the next directly.

Comment: Sorry to say, but if still had to pass an argument to `Step2()` then `if (_foo != null) Step2(_foo);` I think it might just do the same :)

Comment: @AqibChattha: note that the argument passed to `Step2` is not nullable. There will be no warning in `Step2`. This pattern allows a logical transition from one step to the next without an additional `_foo !=  null`. It may even allow to remove the `_foo` field completely.

Comment: Sorry, it is not an additional condition as it is directly being called in `Step1()`, and since the argument `Step2()` accepts is not nullable, so still there will be no warnings. My point is that the question does not allow the use of arguments and only attributes, and if we can use arguments there are very easy and straightforward methods so why complicate it :>

Comment: The OP's solution requires an additional `if != null` or `!` inside `Step2` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I am referring to: `private static void Step1() { if (_foo != null) Step2(_foo); } private static void Step2(string foo) { /* use foo here */ }` now using `foo` will not generate a warning as it is not a nullable argument. It also reduces the unnecessary steps involved and follows the **KISS** principle.

Comment: You are right. The parametrized Step2 alone would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is adding an assertion at the top of the method: `Debug.Assert(_foo is not null);`.
This clearly encodes a program invariant, enforces it in DEBUG code and removes the warning on the subsequent `Console.WriteLine(foo.Length);`